# DscTemplate isn't executing my SetScript

Tags: powershell, dsc

```
$Launcher_PackageFile = "Launcher.exe"
$Launcher_PackageDestinationDirectory = "$Env:ProgramData\Launcher";
#$Launcher_StartupDirectory = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace(0x07)
$Launcher_Source = "$Env:PackageRoot\Launcher\$Launcher_PackageFile" 

Script UpdateConfigurationVersion
{
    GetScript = { 
        # For cmdlet. Must always return a hash table.
        return @{
            "Name"="LauncherPackage"
            "Version"="Latest"
        };
    }          
    TestScript = {
        # Check if the file is in the folder
        $TestPath = Join-Path $Launcher_PackageDestinationDirectory $Launcher_PackageFile

        if (Test-Path $TestPath) {
            return $true;
        }

        return $false;
    }
    SetScript = { 
        # Logic
        #move the exe
        if (!Test-Path $Launcher_PackageDestinationDirectory) {
            New-Item -Type Directory -Path $Launcher_PackageDestinationDirectory
        }

        Copy-Item -Path $Launcher_Source -Destination $Launcher_PackageDestinationDirectory 

        #TODO Create a shortcut to the startup directory 
        #or create a task in the scheduler
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect syntax 
 **(!Test-Path**

```
if (!(Test-Path $Launcher_PackageDestinationDirectory)) {....
```

or

```
if (-not(Test-Path $Launcher_PackageDestinationDirectory) {....
```

Also add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your `Test-Path` command to suppress error.

Answer (score 1):

With that info is difficult to tell.

Add messages to TestScript and SetScript to see what's going on. For example:

```
Write-Verbose -Message 'Testing if already exists'
```

TestScript gets executed before SetScript, check whether is returning true or false (by adding messages). TestScript may be returning true and thus the SetScript is not running. Output $TestPath to see if the path is correct.

Then check the logs on C:\Windows\System32\Configuration\ConfigurationStatus